# expose files from docker container to host

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have a docker container that holds a django app. The static files are produced and copied to a static folder. 
container folder hierarchy:

```
- var
    - django
        - app
        - static
```

before i build the docker image, i run `./manage.py collectstatic` so the static files are in the `/var/django/static` folder. To expose the app and serve the static files, i have on the host an nginx. The problem is that if i do a volume between the static folder and a designated folder on the host, when i run the docker container, the `/var/django/static` folder in the container gets deleted (well, not deleted but mounted). Is there any way to overcome this? as in set the volume but tell docker to take the current files as well?

Comment: Why not build a `nginx` docker image instead? So what you would do here is to do whatever that is needed to `build` your django web application and then add (using dockerfile's `ADD` keyword) to push the static files into the the nginx image?

Comment: because thats how our qa/integration/production env works. the nginx is on the host and does not run on docker.

Comment: I see. So you are looking at mounting a container's files out onto the host which is pretty unconventional because people typically do it the other way round. So what is the purpose of having a container where you are only interested in its files? Why not just symbolic link the static file directory to the directory which `ngix` will serve its files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Volumes are treated as mounts in Docker, which means the host directory will always be mounted over the container's directory. In other words, what you're trying to do isn't currently possible with Docker volumes.

See this Github issue for a discussion on this subject: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4361

One possible work-around would be to have a docker volume to an empty directory in your container, and then in your Docker RUN command (or start-up script), copy the static contents into that empty directory that is mounted as a volume.

Comment: My solution was close to yours. After i started the container and mounted the volume, i just ran anothe collectstatic command which repopulated the volume with the files.

Comment: to clarify, are you saying that one can get around this issue in the build process by executing copy so this is taken care of automatically? Do you mean the Dockerfile COPY command? or use RUN "cp /files1 /files2"?  I can populate the mounted directory by executing commands in the container after the fact, but this feels like an unnecessary and avoidable manual step.

Answer (score 7):

Reading from: [Dockers Volume Page](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

> Volumes have several advantages over bind mounts:
>
> New volumes can have their content pre-populated by a container.

---

[Similar example using docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59369740/9656767)

Using nginx's default webpage folder as the example:

```
$ docker volume create xmpl
$ docker run -v xmpl:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

Will yield all the files on the **host** system via:

```
$ docker inspect xmpl
...
"Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/xmpl/_data"
```

And you can then view the files on the **host**:

```
# ls /var/lib/docker/volumes/xmpl/_data                               
  50x.html  index.html
```

And finally to use it from **/var/nginx/static**:

```
# mkdir -p /var/nginx
# ln -s /var/lib/docker/volumes/xmpl/_data /var/nginx/static
# ls /var/nginx/static
  50x.html  index.html
```

Comment: Note that the `volumes` directory is owned by root and not group or world readable, at least on Debian/Ubuntu. nginx probably cannot see those files even with the symlink.

Answer (score 6):

Another nice solution:
 1. Install SSHd
 2. Install SSHFS on Host
 3. Mount folder inside docker container to outside (host) by SSHFS

Comment: waste of resources, why encrypt everything -_-