# How to map a docker containers directory to the host with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Given following docker-compose.yml setup:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  reverse:
    container_name: nginx-reverse-proxy
    hostname: nginx-reverse-proxy
    image: nginx:stable
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 433:433
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./config
        target: /etc/nginx
        consistency: consistent
```

this results in `./config` folder being mapped to the container `nginx-reverse-proxy` and therefore in an empty `/etc/nginx` directory inside the container.

**Goal**: 
Mapping a folder **from** container **to** host. In my example **from** container `/etc/nginx` **to** the host `./config`.

My current search constantly results in mapping a directoy **from** host **to** container (which i do not want).

Any hints/solutions are appreciated. Thanks!

My current solution is ugly:
I created the container with docker and copied the files from `/etc/nginx` to `./config`. Removing the container and using the `docker-compose up` works and `nginx` starts because the needed files are already on the host.

Edit: The folder is not present at creation. Docker compose is creating the folder as stated in the docs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading from: [Dockers Volume Page](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

> Volumes have several advantages over bind mounts:
>
> New volumes can have their content pre-populated by a container.

---

So a simple docker-compose (inside a folder called nginx):

```
version: "3.7"
volumes:
  xmpl:

services:
  testnginx:
    image: nginx:stable
    volumes:
      - xmpl:/etc/nginx
```

Will yield all the files on the **host** system via:

```
$ docker-compose up
$ docker inspect nginx_xmpl
...
"Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/nginx_xmpl/_data"
```

And you can then view the files on the **host**:

```
# ls /var/lib/docker/volumes/nginx_xmpl/_data                               
  conf.d       fastcgi_params koi-utf    koi-win  
  mime.types   modules        nginx.conf scgi_params    
  uwsgi_params win-utf
```

And finally to use it from *./config*:

```
# ln -s /var/lib/docker/volumes/nginx_xmpl/_data ./config
# ls config
  conf.d       fastcgi_params koi-utf    koi-win  
  mime.types   modules        nginx.conf scgi_params    
  uwsgi_params win-utf
```

Comment: Thank You Tyler. This is what i was looking for! Short, simple and clear.

Comment: This does work but I believe it is a 'launch only' solution. If/when you update the files in the container they will not be present on the host until you go back and delete the volume and let docker re-create it in the process of `docker-compose up`. If you don't do this the host files always are 'mounted over' the container files. I use this solution but it is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is not possible since containers are just "runnable images" and stored like a batch of zip files in the fs. On run event, they are flattened to a "folder" where Linux core does a `chroot` and starts processes using this root.

OPTIONALLY you can at the end of the process map some paths from the host OS to some paths in the `chrooted folder`, but not the way back. When Docker makes the mapping, it `replaces` path completely, so all the existing files in the path will "hidden" from the image fs and "replaced" by the mapped host path.

I think you want to take a look at "default files configuration" for a path in an image. There are two ways from my point of view:

- Start a container with mapped path to another directory and when your container starts just copy the required folder contents using the container shell to the mapped folder. Example: let's map `/export` to the host's `./exported-configs` and when container starts go into the running container using `docker exec {.... extra params and docker ps id} bash` and run something like `cp -R /etc/nginx /export/nginx-configs`.
- export the whole image filesystem using https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/ and take a look at the interesting image configuration and so it.

Both ways are working, usually, I do the first one if I need any folders from the image.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Well, you shouldn't do the mapping the way you do it, cause as you said it's ugly.
The most convenient and hassle-free way to do it is like so:

```
version: '3.7'

    services:
      reverse:
        container_name: nginx-reverse-proxy
        hostname: nginx-reverse-proxy
        image: nginx:stable
        ports:
          - 80:80
          - 433:433
        volumes:
          - ./nginx-conf/myapp/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
          - ./nginx-conf/myapp/sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled


    volumes:
      nginx-conf:
    networks:
      myapp-net:
        driver: bridge
```

The location **/etc/nginx** contains also other files, (mime.types and fastcgi_params for instance) which will not exist if you map the host directory **./config**, unless of course, you copy them to the host instead, but that's not a pretty solution.

Above, i just mapped a local nginx.conf file, located in /nginx/myapp folder to /etx/nginx/nginx.conf and a local sites-enabled folder to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled folder in the container.

You would be better off by keeping things as simple as possible because docker is already complicated by nature.

Comment: This wouldn't override the file in the container